# Python 3 - Serialize generated numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, serialization, generator

I have a program that generates say a million numpy arrays of size 784, and I want to save them on a file as they are being generated (so only one array is kept in memory at any time). I tried the code below that seems to hold up when `n_arrays` is in the order of 10^5 (memory usage goes up by about 400MB but then drops back and keeps doing so until finished).
When 10^6 however memory usage goes up until it hits the limit and throws MemoryError.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
import numpy as np


def generator(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield np.array(range(784))
        num += 1


class StreamArray(list):
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.n = n
        self.len = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return generator(self.n)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len


n_arrays = 10**6
np.save('out', StreamArray(n_arrays))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def generator(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield np.array(range(784))
        num += 1


n_arrays = 10**6
with open('out.npy', 'wb') as f:
    for item in generator(n_arrays):
        np.save(f, item)
```

Comment: That saves the bytes of every array in one file but loading it only shows the first (i.e. `len(np.load('out.npy'))` should print 10^6 but prints 784 instead)

Comment: with open('out.py', 'rb') as f: np.load(f,) first one, np.load(f) second one and so on... Don't close the file.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: And then? Where do I use `np.load()`?

Comment: `with open('out.npy', 'rb') as f:    print(len(np.load(f)))` still gives 784.

Comment: You don't have to use with open. Just use f = open('out.pny', 'rb') and don't close the file. To get an array, use np.load(f) .  Each time you load, you will get the next array.

Comment: Ohh I missed the part where "Each time you load, you will get the next array". Thanks.